# Uneven tables by bootstrap on HTML

Tags: html

Need to create a uneven table on HTML like that ( SM version for Mobile Phones )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r48sD.png

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that all columns should add up to 12.

So, the first set of columns need to be 6 width if you want two columns side by side. **2**x6=12.

The second set of columns need to be 4 width if you want three of them side by side. **3**x4=12.

The third set of columns can be any width but you seem to want them fairly slim and centered horizontally.

```
<div class="row">

   <!-- first 2 columns inside a row -->

   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <!-- Column content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <!-- Column content -->
   </div>

   <!-- Next 3 columns inside the same row --> 

  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <!-- Column content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <!-- Column content -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <!-- Column content -->
   </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

   <!-- Final 5 stacked columns inside a
new row or you could put them in the above
row if you wanted. `mx-auto` will center each
column instead of placing them side by side -->

   <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
      <!-- Column content -->
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
      <!-- Column content -->
   </div>   
   <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
      <!-- Column content -->
   </div>    
   <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
      <!-- Column content -->
   </div>  
</div>
```

Please also read here for good Stack Overflow tips.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example